# changing malloc to new causes error

Tags: c++

There is a code at  http://sequitur.info/sequitur_simple.cc

I changed the `malloc` and `free` lines

```
R = (rules **) malloc(sizeof(rules *) * num_rules);
free(R);
```

to `new` and `delete`

```
R = (rules **) new(sizeof(rules *) * num_rules);  //ERROR
delete(R);
```

However `g++` shows this error:

```
error: expected type-specifier before â;â token
error: invalid conversion from âlong unsigned intâ to âvoid*â [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/new:103:14: error:   initializing argument 2 of âvoid* operator new(std::size_t, void*)â [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: What's the type of `R` and `rules`?

Comment: Maybe try `new rules*[num_rules];`

Comment: C++ is not C, you don't pass `new` the number of bytes to allocate.  `new` deals with objects.

Comment: `new` is not a function you call, and neither is `delete`. Not directly like you try to do anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your variable types are correct, it should be

```
R = new rules*[num_rules];
```

Later, when you're to free it, use

```
delete[] R;
```

---

But likely, OP is trying to solve the "wrong" problem here (assumptions made when designing this piece of code likely isn't correct...). 
For more details, refer to Jerry Coffin's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15018444/690061)

About when `new` is used like a function (placement new), refer to refp's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15018377/690061)

Comment: Given the OP doesn't know how to use `new`, it might be best to mention that, with an array new, he'd also need array delete.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` and `new` both allocate storage but they are substantially different, not only logically but in syntax as well. One is a plain function, the other is an operator.

---

To allocate storage for `num_rules` `rules*` you'll need to use something as the below.

```
rules ** R;

...

R = new rules* [num_rules];

...

delete [] R;
```

---

#### But I've seen `new` called as a function?

Not really, you might have seen something that look like a *function-call* but that isn't really the case.

In the below snippet we will tell new to initialize an object at *adress* `0x123123`, we are **not** allocating  memory for `0x123123` number of `Obj`'s. This is normally referred to as *"placement-new"*.

```
Obj * p = new (0x123123) Obj;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one where you really ought to look carefully at the code before doing anything.

    <strike>void print()
    {
      R = (rules **) malloc(sizeof(rules *) * num_rules);
      memset(R, 0, sizeof(rules *) * num_rules);
      R[0] = &S;
      Ri = 1;</strike>

```
  for (int i = 0; i < Ri; i ++) {
    cout << i << " -> ";
    p(R[i]);
  }
  free(R);
}
```

Look at that carefully. Take particular note of the fact that it's allocating space for `num_rules` pointers, but really only *uses* exactly *one* of those pointers (`R[0]`).

Instead of rewriting the code to change from `malloc` to `new` you should eliminate the dynamic allocation entirely, and simplify the code a lot in the process, getting something like:

```
void print() { 
    cout << "0 -> " << p(&S);
}
```

I suppose I should add that I didn't analyze `p` very thoroughly -- I suppose it's possible it's actually using that extra data that was allocated. If so, the code needs ever more serious rewriting -- that's just too horrible of a thing to allow (and, unfortunately, the fact that `R` and `Ri` are globals indicates that's all too likely).

Bottom line: no matter how you look at it, you're attacking the wrong problem here. `malloc` vs. `new` is entirely the wrong place to look.

If you do decide to make a change, it looks like you can use a `std::vector` here without any problems.

```
void print() { 
    std::vector<rules *> R(num_rules);

    R[0] = &S;

    // ...
}
```

Edit: looking a bit more at `p`, it looks like my second thoughts were justified -- I'm pretty sure the first rewrite won't work correctly. `p` is not only using the remaining space in `R`, but *also* modifying `Ri`, so what initially looks like a loop that will only execute once will really execute multiple times.

Conclusion: calling the guy who wrote this mess a worthless cretinous moron would be an insult to worthless cretinous morons.